# How to change the div attribute data-x data-y thanks to jquery

Tags: jquery

the example below is used to make a slider thanks to impress.js

Example :
`<div id="overview" class="step" data-x="3000" data-y="1500" data-scale="10"> </div>`

So the thing that i want to do is to change the value of data-x,data-y and data-scale.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's data methods:

```
$("#overview").data("x", 4000);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grahampcharles/LF3rv/